# autorelease alternative on ios5

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5

What is the alternative to autorelease in ios5? Previously the following method for table views would work:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    static NSString *TableIdentifier = @"TableIndentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                  reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier]autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arrAccounts objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
```

How ever now i get a message "ARC forbids" and "autorelease is unavailable"... what is the work around for this?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that ARC is a compiler feature ,not an iOS 5 feature. So you should be able to run ARC compiled apps on previous iOS versions. And you don't need to use ARC if you don't want to, you can turn it off and keep using retain release.

Comment: @Stefan that is not exactly true. The OS has to support ARC as well. That is, there is no ARC support in anything prior to iOS4.

Answer (score 11):

simply remove the autorelease, ARC does the work for you

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                  reuseIdentifier:TableIdentifier];
```

It's damn magic

Answer (score 3):

Remove the autorelease call. AFAIK the compiler is smart enough to realize that it should be autoreleased and synthesizes the appropriate calls for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to make the required changes for ARC to the current file you can disable ARC for a specific file using a new -fno-objc-arc compiler flag for that file. ARC is enabled using a new -fobjc-arc compiler flag. You can choose to use ARC on a per-file basis if it’s more convenient for you to use manual reference counting for some files. More info:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

Comment: This is a magnificent answer - especially where you're dealing with 3rd party code. Note the URL has been updated to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html and specifically what you need to do is open the target > Build Phases tab > Expand 'Compile Source' > For any files where you still want to use autorelease add '-fno-objc-arc'